# C++ Pizza Order Program not sure why the errors are happening

Tags: c++

I'm new at programming so I'm not really sure what the problem is. The errors I keep getting are in the `AddTopping(string toppings)`. One is `illegal reference to non-static member PizzaOrder::toppings` . The other one is `'initializing' can not convert for " to std::string.`

This is what I've got at the moment:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class PizzaOrder
{
private:
   static const int MAX_SIZE=1000;
   int size;
   string toppings[MAX_SIZE];
   int num_toppings;
public:
   static const string toppings_offered [4];
   static const int DEFAULT_SIZE= 0;
   static const int DEFAULT_TOPPINGS=0;
   static const double topping_base_cost;
   static const double base_price;

   PizzaOrder ();
   PizzaOrder (int size);
   bool SetSize (int size);
   int GetSize () {return size;}
   static string AddTopping (string topping);
   static int AddTopping (int n);
   static double GetPrice ();
   static string StringizeSize ();
   static string GetToppings ();
   static void DisplayPizza();
};
const double PizzaOrder :: topping_base_cost= .5;
const double PizzaOrder :: base_price= 5;
const string PizzaOrder ::toppings_offered[4]={"olives","bell peppers","onions","pepperoni"};
int main ()
{
   PizzaOrder order;
   char pizza_size;
   int topping_choice;

   short array_size = sizeof(order.toppings_offered)/sizeof(order.toppings_offered[0]);



   cout << "Would you like a size [S]small , [M]medium, [L]large pizza or [Q]quit?" <<endl;
   while ( pizza_size != 'Q' || pizza_size != 'q')
   {
      cin >> pizza_size;
      if( pizza_size == 'S' || pizza_size == 's')
         order.SetSize(0);
      if(pizza_size == 'M' || pizza_size == 'm')
         order.SetSize(1);
      if(pizza_size == 'L' || pizza_size == 'l')
         order.SetSize(2);
      while (topping_choice !=0)
      {
         cout << "Current Pizza : " << order.StringizeSize () << order.GetToppings ();
         cout <<"Select an item by number. (Enter 0 when done)" << endl;
         for (int i=0; i< array_size-1; i++)
         {
            cout << (i+1) << ". " << order.toppings_offered[i]<< endl;
         }
         cout << "Selection?";
         cin >>topping_choice;
         order.AddTopping(topping_choice);
      }
   }

         return 0;
}
PizzaOrder::PizzaOrder()
{
   size=DEFAULT_SIZE;
   num_toppings=DEFAULT_TOPPINGS;
}
PizzaOrder::PizzaOrder(int size)
{
   if(!SetSize(size))
      size=DEFAULT_SIZE;
}
bool PizzaOrder::SetSize(int size)
{
   if (size != 0 || size !=1 || size !=2)
      return false;
   this -> size=size;
   return true;
}
string PizzaOrder::AddTopping(string topping)
{
   string temp_toppings[]={toppings};
   short array_size = sizeof(temp_toppings)/sizeof(temp_toppings[0]);
   num_toppings+1;
   toppings[num_toppings];
   for(int k=0; k<array_size-1; k++)
   {
      toppings[k]= num_toppings[k];
   }
   toppings[num_toppings]= topping;

}
int PizzaOrder::AddTopping(int n)
{
   string temp_toppings[]={toppings};
   short array_size = sizeof(temp_toppings)/sizeof(temp_toppings[0]);
   num_toppings+1;
   toppings[num_toppings];
   for(int k=0; k<array_size-1; k++)
   {
      toppings[k]= num_toppings[k];
   }
   toppings[num_toppings]=toppings_offered[n];
}
double PizzaOrder ::GetPrice()
{
   double price;
   double multiplier;
   if(size==0)
      multiplier=1;
   if(size==1)
      multiplier=1.15;
   if (size==2)
      multiplier=1.25;
   price= (base_price*multiplier)+(num_toppings*topping_base_cost);
   return price;
}
string PizzaOrder::StringizeSize()
{
   if(size==0)
      return "small";
   if(size==1)
      return "medium";
   if (size==2)
      return "large";
}
string PizzaOrder::GetToppings()
{
   string temp= "";
   for(int x=0,x<num_toppings-1, x++)
      temp+= "+ " + toppings[x];

   return temp;

}
void PizzaOrder::DisplayPizza()
{
   cout << StringizeSize ()<< GetTopping () << GetPrice ();
}
```

Comment: i tried to format it with ctrl K but failed. Im new at this be gentle

Comment: Could I have some fries with that?

Comment: what is {toppings} suppose to do? and where you have 'initializing' (or you get the eror wrong)

Comment: In `int PizzaOrder::AddTopping(int n)`, this `num_toppings+1;` has no effect. Probably, I think you intended to do `num_toppings += 1;`

Comment: @muntoo: Nah, it's probably Pizza Hut's new and improved ordering system.

Comment: You are trying to write a big program all at once. Try writing something small at first, that does only a little of what you want, *get that working perfectly*, then add features one at a time. Never add code to a program that doesn't compile.

Answer (score 2):

You have a bunch of static functions that shouldn't be static, including AddTopping.  Read up on static.

I'm not absolutely sure which line you're getting the "initializing cannot convert from" error on (please provide complete error information, including line numbers, in future questions), but I'd wager it's that first line in the integer overload of AddTopping.  I gather that you're trying to copy the contents of the current "toppings" array member (inaccessible to you because you've declared the function static -- which is probably the reason that the type information is missing in the error message) into a temp_toppings array.  The line, as you've written it, is not valid C++.  I suggest you Google "C++ copy array" and read the first link, which is a nice array tutorial on the augustcouncil.com Web site.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you get rid of all mistakes, you have a infinite loop running with the very beginning condition in the while loop -

The intention of this loop is to break from the loop, I assume. But it never does so -

```
while ( pizza_size != 'Q' || pizza_size != 'q')
{
    // .....
}
```

When `pizza_size` is equal to `Q`, with the `||` condition, the condition turns out to be true and an infinite loop. It should be -

pizza_size = 'Q' => false || true  => true -> while loop continues
pizza_size = 'q' => true  || false => true -> while loop continues

```
while ( (pizza_size != 'Q') && (pizza_size != 'q'))
{
    // .....
}
```

Hope it helps at later stages.